# Need help understanding this Python list syntax

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm having trouble understanding what this syntax means in Python:

```
out = out[lengths - 1, range(len(lengths))]
```

Why is there a range inside a list? How does that work? For context, I'm training a machine learning model in PyTorch. lengths is a list of the lengths of the input.

Comment: Please define `out` and `input`, or provide the link to which you are referring.

Comment: That's not a list.

Answer (score 2):

I assume `lengths` is an array of integers. (probably a Numpy array)

The first index `lengths - 1` will give a list of indices that is subtracted by `-1`.
The second index `range(len(lengths))` will give a list of numbers from 0 to the size of `lengths`.

I don't know what the specific logic is in your code, but in general, you can give a list of indices to pick the data at specific locations.

```
out = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
-> array([[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]])

first_idx = [0, 1, 2]
second_idx = [2, 1, 0]
# (0,2), (1,1), (2,0)

out[first_idx, second_idx]
-> array([3, 5, 7])
```

Comment: Clever! Thank you very much.